# Testing java mongodb driver source with mongodb running remotly

Tags: mongodb

I have made changes to [source code](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-java-driver), I require to run all testcases to check its effect using command

> ./gradlew check

I am having the mongodb running in remote machine. Can anyone help me in configuring java mongodb driver with remotely running mongodb.

Answer (score 0):

you need to import the java driver to your project.

```
import com.mongodb.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoDatabase;
```

then you need to connect to the mongoDB on your server, it can be localhost or it can be your server. also you can choose which port to use:

```
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);
```

then you can connect to your db:

```
MongoDatabase db = mongoClient.getDatabase("test");
```

and to connect to one of your collections, and make actions on it:

```
db.getCollection("restaurants").insertOne(
        new Document("address",
                new Document()
                        .append("street", "2 Avenue")
                        .append("zipcode", "10075")
                        .append("building", "1480")
                        .append("coord", asList(-73.9557413, 40.7720266)))
                .append("borough", "Manhattan")
                .append("cuisine", "Italian")
                .append("grades", asList(
                        new Document()
                                .append("grade", "A")
                                .append("score", 11),
                        new Document()
                                .append("grade", "B")
                                .append("score", 17)))
                .append("name", "Vella")
                .append("restaurant_id", "41704620"));
```

Comment: I wanted to run testcases of java_mongodb_driver.

Answer (score 0):

One can pass the connection string while starting testcases

```
./gradlew check -Dorg.mongodb.test.uri=mongodb://example.com:27017/
```